# How to change spotlight's font?

Tags: macos, big-sur, spotlight

How can I choose the font that Spotlight's search box uses?

The font family/typeface

Answer (score 0):

You can't (easily**). Apple is not a big fan of allowing the user to customize the OS.

** I dare say that it's possible, but it would likely require very invasive modifications to the system, which would compromise a range of security features, and need re-applying every time there's an update.

Comment: Unless things have changed, it's also my understanding that once the _seal_ on the _cryptographically signed read-only volume_ is broken by the user that **FileVault** can no longer be used on the drive.